# iPhone refresh a view from another class

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to be able to refresh a view from another class, but nothing I have tried is working. My application is a tabbed application with several tabs set up. I have a method called refresh in my ViewController1 class that looks like this

```
-(void)TestMe{


     NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"widgjson" ofType:@"json"];  
     NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  

     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
     NSString *docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"json.txt"];
     [responseString writeToFile:docFile atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:Nil];

     [self loadView];
     [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

This works fine. When the application first loads up, it loads a different json, then when I click this button it loads a new JSON and then updates the view. This is just temporary to test out refreshing. However if I try to call this method from another class, or from the AppDelegates ApplicationDidEnterForeground methods, nothing happens. I tried calling it like this

```
 -(void)TestMe{


    ViewController1 *vc = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];


    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"widgjson" ofType:@"json"];  
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSString *docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"json.txt"];
    [responseString writeToFile:docFile atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:Nil];

    [vc loadView];
    [vc viewDidLoad];

}
```

So why does this method not work from any other classes. All I want to is to be able to refresh a view from another class or when the application loads up, but just can't seem to find anything that works.

Would be very grateful if someone could point me in right direction!

EDIT: UPDATING TO CLARIFY

Okay, what I have done for the time being which I don't like is put this

```
exit(0);
```

Inside AppDelegates ApplicationDidEnterBackground. This works to an extent, but is not an ideal solution.

What I would like to have happen is that when application is opened again, the AppDelegate gets run again which sets up the tabs. The JSON pulled from the server can affect the order of the tabs which is why I need the AppDelegates ApplicationDidFinishLaunching method to reload itself again.

Also I would like to know can I do this from another class in the application. The first time my application is loaded it asks for the users phone number, which is sent to the server which then generates an PIN. After this is done, then I want the AppDelegate method to load up and begin setting up the tabs and the order etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent your application running in the background (and so to force reloading when you exit and re-enter) you can set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to `YES` in your info.plist.

However, this is probably a bit drastic.

Your current code for refreshing from the application delegate is a non-starter because you are creating a new instance of the view controller rather than talking to one that is on the screen.

For this reason it is best not to involve your application delegate at all in the process.

Instead, your view controller can register itself as an observer for the [`UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) notification, and do whatever it needs to itself. You would typically register for this notification on viewDidLoad, and unregister on viewDidUnload (since, by definition, if you have unloaded the view, you don't need to refresh it when the app comes back up!).

You would register as follows (using blocks here as they are the future):

Declare an ivar of type id to hold the observer object, let's call it `becomeActiveObserver` in this case. So, wherever you are declaring your ivars, add `id becomeActiveObserver`. Then, in viewDidLoad:

```
becomeActiveObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActive 
object:nil 
queue: nil 
usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){ 
    //put your reloading code in here
    [self TestMe];
}];
```

And remove like so in viewDidUnload:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:becomeActiveObserver;
```

You can follow a similar pattern to pick up notifications (your own, or system ones) from anywhere else in your app. This is a better design than passing everything through the app delegate as it involves much looser coupling.

Comment: Interesting, kind of new to iPhone programming so wasn't too sure of how to use Notification centre. I tried out your code, however I am getting an error message around usingBlock part, it says "Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(void)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSNotification *__strong)'"

Also quick question, can this code be used on phones with IOS below 5.0?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the parameter - see edit. This works on 4.0 and above.

Comment: Code works perfectly, thanks a lot!!! Spent ages trying to do figure out that using the app delegate methods, this method is way easier. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: The more iPhone programming you do, the less you put in the app delegate.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example by any chance of how to call this from another view. This code is currently in tab1, and I want to be able to refresh tab1 content from tab2. How would I send the notification from tab2 to tab1 telling it to refresh

Comment: Don't think of it like that. Think of tab 2 posting a notification (you can make your own up with a unique string for the name) and tab 1 listening to it. So you'd have the same code as in the answer, but you'd listen for a different notification name, and in the other tab you'd post the notification - see nsnotificationcentre class ref.

Comment: Just realized I forgot to award you the bounty :P Sorry about that, but first time I have used a bounty, I assumed it automatically awarded the bounty to the person after I accepted their answer.

Comment: I thinkit happens automatically when it expires, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I guess clickMe is an action to a button.if you want to refresh the viewcontroller at startup then add a function in viewcontroller similar to clickme or any function that refreshes the view and call it from applicationWillEnterForeground method or you may try this :-

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
{     
NSLog(@"app will enter foreground");     
[viewController clickMe:NULL]; 
}
```

and you may change the file in the applicationWillEnterForeground method of appDelegate if your application requires.

Comment: I already tried that but doesnt work. I also have a void version of that function to test out, no luck. The annoying thing is, it does run ViewDidLoad again, as if I have NSLOG(@"test"); in viewDidLoad, it will print out again everytime the app loads up, however nothing else will work apart from printed statements. I did that loadview function to work so it clears everything, then viewdidload to reload it, but nothing apart from print statements will work and I dont know why

Comment: move the refresh code from viewdidload and other viewDid... into a different function and call that function from applicationWillEnterForeground (and also from your viewDid...).